# Valid travel purposes between Romania and Croatia during the Covid-19 pandemic?

Tags: eu, covid-19

Can a Romanian citizen move from Romania to Croatia during this pandemic?

My girlfriend would come to live with me and stay until the end of the general lockdown.

Croatia has laws saying people who come from non critical countries will be advised to self isolate, and there's quarantine for people from critical places, but that was before the bit tighter lockdown while travel was still possible.

What would be the way to come? What kind of paperwork would be needed on both sides?

Comment: This is really a topic that can only be answered by local Croatian officials correctly. Some form of paperwork confirming that she may be quarantined at your place of residence may be needed. Something for transit through Serbia may also be needed. All of this is highly dependent on local conditions.

Comment: She'd either go through Hungary by bus/train or fly if there are any planes, since Serbia is not in EU and that does complicate travel a bit. Do you think it would be necesary to get additional paperwork for Hungary?

Comment: They may want some sort of confirmation that she would have no problems entering Croatia. So first find out what Croatia may issue and contact the Hungarians what they may need (possibly confirmation of Croatian paperwork). Assume, at the moment, that this will likely be considered non essential travel.

Comment: @Affaltar Contact the border authorities and explain in detail. For Croatia, e-mail policija@mup.hr, and for Hungary, e-mail hatarrendfoo@orfk.police.hu. Hungary currently refuses entry to most foreigners, but may grant a waiver.